# Why use "entre el de nata y la torta" instead of "entre la nata y la torta"?

Tags: gramática

I'm a beginner of Spanish language. I came up with the following sentence on *Easy Spanish Step-by-step* by Barbara Bregstein.

In lesson 12, there's a sentence:

> No puedo escoger ***entre el de nata y la torta*** con crema y fruta.

My understanding is:

> I can't choose between the cream and the cake with cream and fruit.

However, I cannot figure out why it's not "entre la nata y la torta" as nata is a feminine noun.

Thank you for your explanation in advance!

Comment: I wonder if the first cake is using "el" because it's *un pastel.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me change an ingredient in your sentence because I'm not sure how English speakers differentiate **nata** from cream but those two are different from an Spanish point of view.

> No puedo escoger entre el **de** chocolate y la torta de crema y fruta.

Notice that I've highlighted the preposition "de" that you have omitted in your English translation.

You can translate that sentence as

> I can't choose between the **chocolated** one and the cake with cream and fruit.

where [chocolated](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chocolated) means

> having or containing chocolate

As pointed by @Traveller, more naturally you can just say

> I can't choose between the chocolate one and the cake with cream and fruit

The first option is not chocolate by itself, it's **a dessert whose main ingredient is chocolate**.

In your original sentence, the first option is the dessert made **of** nata - being "of" the usual English translation of "de" - where **dessert made** has been omitted.

> No puedo escoger entre el (**dulce hecho**) de nata y la torta de crema y fruta.

Comment: More naturally, it could be translated as “I can’t choose between the chocolate one or the cake with cream and fruit”.

Comment: @Traveller I wasn't completely sure. Updating ... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Now, I understand.

Comment: After looking at the Wikipedia article I can see what the difference between _nata_ and _crema_ is but I do not think there is an equivalent pair of words in English.